# How can I find out the size of a video file on my iPhone 6 camera roll?

Tags: iphone, ios

How can I find out the size of a video file on my iPhone 6 camera roll without connecting it to a computer.

Answer (score 5):

The Shortcuts app made this actually rather easy nowadays. Configure it as an extension for the share sheet, then activate it in any video (or photo) within Photos.

[image]

PS: Shortcuts is part of recent versions of iOS. For first time users it might help to have a look at the [Shortcut Manual](https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/welcome/ios).

Comment: Very nice solution

Comment: I did this. The 'Choose' screen said compressing with a progress bar \for about 1 minute before reporting the size. I am guessing, then, that it's reporting the compressed size, not the size on disk. And for those (like me) who didn't know, 'Shortcuts' is an app by Apple available in the app store.

Comment: Don't you need a 3rd party app for this? Not a very useful answer if you don't explain all of the steps involved.

Comment: @GarfieldKlon Happy to add details. What exactly are you missing?

Comment: this answer is totally incomplete. There are no steps explained how you achieved this, or if there is another app that is needed.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid Which other app are you referring to, and which steps are you missing?

Comment: This answer doesnt explain in any detail how to get to the screen you posted, or what to do.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid Shortcuts is part of iOS, the explanations on how to use it in general are in the manual linked to in the answer. Apple explains this much better than I could ever do :-)

Comment: I have created an answer for anyone using IOS 14 here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/409992/176218

Answer (score 3):

Another 3rd party app option is the Google Photos application.  You can click a photo or video and select 'info'.  It doesn't require initiating an upload and then canceling it.

I wish this was built into the native iOS Photos app, but at least Google Photos is free and comes from a reputable vendor.

Answer (score 1):

Both OneDrive and Dropbox etc. show you the file size as soon as you start to upload the video. Once you've glanced at the video size,  there's nothing stopping you from cancelling the upload right away so you dont spend unnecessary data.

An option that needs no upload is the [View Exif app extension](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/viewexif/id945320815?mt=8) - it will process the video file on your phone/iPad and tell you the size of the video and no need to leverage another service.

Comment: ViewExif doesn't work with videos.

Answer (score 1):

I have created an easy and complete iOS Shortcut inspired by @nohillside.

[image: Shortcut screenshot]

Get the Shortcut from iCloud (no app installation is needed):
https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/642e55dc8163480a8658c3f16c9a2a65

You can find Media Metadata in the share sheet of your images/videos.

You may want to enable Allow Untrusted Shortcuts in Settings > Shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

you can add it to an email message to check the approximate size. when you attempt to send the mail I believe it shows the size of the attached photo/video

Comment: iOS often [compress videos](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39105/does-the-iphone-compress-emailed-videos) somewhat before showing the compose email window, I believe. As a result, this solution may yield somewhat unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

Download the [<sub>[image]</sub> Photo Investigator](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photo-investigator-edit-remove-gps-exif-metadata/id571574618?mt=8&at=1001lwpF) app from the iOS App Store and select a photo, then look at the File Size at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score -1):

To counteract the absurd of not having the properties of video files in iPhone, search for this app in the App Store: "Video Info Viewer" from Rory Hool. It's free.

Answer (score -3):

try to share video on utube and it will show size of video before uploading to utube.
Also you can upload on icloud can also provide you the size of video. sharing it with airdrop also provide you the size of file you are sharing.