# Where to view photo and movie metadata on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, video

I noticed today when a friend emailed me a movie he shot on his iPhone XR that the quality was only 568 x 320. While trying to get to the bottom of that mystery, I asked my friend to check the video details on the phone, prior to being sent. Neither of us could find a way to view the video information on the phone.

Is there a way to view media information (like file size, dimensions, data taken etc) for photos and movies shot on iPhones?

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/205118/9058

Comment: @nohillside Yes I saw this before posting. There is no information there that is helpful as the answer is incomplete.

Comment: Try https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/2f632e8323a54f0fa1032d2ace5e0b3d (this is an extended version showing both size and dimension)

Comment: This link can be opened in Shortcuts to load an action which then shows size and dimension of photos etc.

Comment: I am finding it very frustrating when you dont provide any other information with that link, and the other things you posted. Its half baked answers without any details. Like what am I supposed to do with that link ? I added it to shortcuts and now what? Please, if you are going to provide answers, at least try and be thorough and explain the entire process.

Comment: I agree, for people which are new to Shortcuts this probably is a bit confusing. Explaining all the details on a level usable for new users is a challenge though (I didn't even know that one needs to open Shortcuts at least once to load actions from links) but I may be able to extend the answer a bit later today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple, in their infinite wisdom, has chosen to hide that information. There are few built-in ways to view it in iOS. You'll need iOS 13 or greater, even so the procedure is (annoyingly enough) a bit of a kludge.

1. Select the file you want info on it.
2. Tap the share button
3. Select the place to share it to as the Files App.

Once that is done you will need to go into the files.app, and "long" (or more accurately "force tap") on the pic or movie you just "shared" and tap "Info" and then "show more."

And *voila* the EXIF data for the file and it only took you about eight steps to do it (sarcasm off...)

There are actually a lot of sites that have [this info.](https://appletoolbox.com/how-to-view-your-photo-metadata-in-ios-13-and-ipados/) And many also have recommendations for apps to display EXIF data more readily.

Comment: So annoying how they push these useless updates without including simple, easy to implement features that are useful to many. So, as for your answer, there is no FILES app available when I press the share button. Go figure.Running 14.2 OIS and ready for an Android

Comment: Scroll to the bottom of the list, tap edit actions and add "Save to Files". Tap Done and you are good to go. You can customize a *lot* of iOS but the Apple Way is to hide the power user features. The trick is to learn where and when to look for the customization options.

Comment: Hi thanks again, but I cant scroll down. When choosing an option for sharing the file, the scrolling is horizontally oriented (at the bottom of the screen, below the preview of the media file). When I reach the end there is a MORE section that opens up a vertically oriented list with Favorites and Suggested apps. In that list there is no edit actions. There is an EDIT function in the top right corner of that but there is no way to add anything

Comment: Hmmmm, not sure. That's not how it is on my iPhone. Maybesomeone else knows, sry...

Comment: what version of IOS are you on?

Comment: @KalamalkaKid you need to scroll down immediatly after pressing the Share button

Answer (score 3):

I am going to answer my own question here with photos for future users who may be struggling with how to find media info on their Iphones. Thanks to Steve who started things off. PS - I am never buying an APple product again after wasting so much time on something that should be simple!

## Question

Is it possible to view photo and movie data on iOS?

## Answer.

Yes.. but it is a series of steps that require many steps. Painful at best.

## Brief description of process

Since we cant simply look at the media information within the Camera Roll, Iphone users are forced to save the file to the 'Files' App which will allow us to see the media information.

## Steps to take to see Media information on Iphone

**1 -** Go to Camera Roll app and select the photo/movie you want to inspect. You can select multiple files by clicking the 'Select' option in the top right corner) after selecting the file(s) click the **'Share'** icon located in the bottom left corner of the screen:

[image]

**2 -** A new screen will appear with the selected photo and the option to select more files if we want. Beneath this are a row of contacts we can share the photo with, and beneath this is another row with some default options to share with other apps like Mail, Facebook, InstaGram etc.

[image]

In this new version of the **'Share Screen'** the previously accessible menus are now hidden on another page lower down which you can access by scrolling up. After scrolling up we can see the hidden menu that shows us where to save to the [Files App](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT206481):

[image]

**3 -** Click on the **'Save to Files'** option and you will be prompted for which directory to save the file to. Chose a directory to save within the Files app, and then open the app after the file is saved.

**4 -** Once the Files app is open, hold your finger on the file you wish to see the info for and a menu will appear:

[image]

Click on the **'Info'** option to see the following information:

Kind, Size, Date Created, Date Modified, Date last opened, diretory of file on phone, Dimensions and tags.

Comment: This is basically the same answer as the one posted by Steve. Like the Screenshots though, they for sure will help people to realize that the sharing sheet extends downwards (something which depending on the phone used is hard to see on the UI).

Comment: Appreciate your effort - note that you can also edit someone else's answer to improve it. So you could have added these useful screenshots to Steve's answer itself as otherwise it becomes a duplicate effort. (Just remember that for next time).

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to see the file size & all other data connected to photos & videos is to use a free app called The Photo Investigator (it’s in the App Store). You can choose to “share” the item from your camera roll, just scroll down until you see “Investigate” & the magnifying glass icon. Click on the app & a new window opens to show all the data! [image: Steps 1-4 to view image DATA]